# dl tabular - missing bottom border line

Tags: html, css, xhtml

There is missing bottom border line gap after `<dt>`

what is causing this and how to fix it?

```
<dl class="rows">
  <dt>Full Name</dt>
  <dd>Peter Gates</dd>

  <dt>Email Address</dt>
  <dd>email@email.com</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .rows dl {
        float: left;
    }

    .rows dt {
        float: left;
        clear: left;
        width: 150px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .rows dd {
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Feel free if css can be impoved and reduced.

Comment: Margin between the `dt` and `dd`?

Comment: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gw4zW/). I don't see the problem (Chrome).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Try unticking "Normalized CSS".

Comment: @thirtydot Yes, that helped a lot :). One can always know their tools a little bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, you need to add `margin: 0` to `.rows dd`.

This is how I'd write/improve your CSS (with the fix):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/gw4zW/3/

```
.rows {
    float: left;
}
.rows dt, .rows dd {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.rows dt {
    clear: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```